# How to find all vertices reachable from a start vertex following directed edges?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How to find all vertices reachable from a given start vertex following directed edges, in a cyclic directed graph given as

```
Graph[{v1, v2, ...}, 
      {v1 -> v11, v1 -> v12, ..., v2 -> v21, v2 -> v21, ..., vn -> vn1, vn -> vn2, ...}]
```

where all the ending vertices of edges `vij` are in the list of vertices `{v1, v2, ...}`.
?

Comment: Have a look at ref/ConnectedComponents. I think  the form ConnectedComponents[graph,{vertex}] might be what you want.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One can use [`VertexOutComponent[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexOutComponent.html) to find all the vertices connected to a given vertex in a directed graph:

```
In[107]:= edges={1->3,1->4,2->4,2->5,3->5,6->7,7->8,8->9,9->10,6->10,1->6,2->7,3->8,4->9,5->10};
In[114]:= vertices=Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[List@@@edges]];
In[115]:= g=Graph[vertices,edges];
In[116]:= {#,VertexOutComponent[g,{#}]}&/@vertices//Grid
Out[116]= 1 {1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
2   {2,4,5,7,8,9,10}
3   {3,5,8,9,10}
4   {4,9,10}
5   {5,10}
6   {6,7,8,9,10}
7   {7,8,9,10}
8   {8,9,10}
9   {9,10}
10  {10}
```

It should work for any directed graph whether it's acyclic or not. The analogue of `VertexOutComponent[]` for undirected graphs is `ConnectedComponents[]`.

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps something like this?

```
edges = {1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 6 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 
   8 -> 9, 9 -> 10, 6 -> 10, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 9, 5 -> 10};

GraphPlot[edges, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
connected[edges_][v_] :=
  Module[{f},
    f[x_] := (f[x] = {}; f[x] = # ⋃ Flatten[f /@ #]& @ ReplaceList[x, edges]);
    f[v]
  ]

connected[edges][2]
```

> ```
> {4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10}
> ```

On large graphs it will be advantageous to convert the `edges` to a `Dispatch` table.

---

Calculation and return of all connections as an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html):

```
allConnected[edges_] :=
  Module[{a = <||>, f},
    f[x_] := (a[x] = {}; a[x] = # ⋃ Flatten[f /@ #] & @ ReplaceList[x, edges]);
    f ~Scan~ Union @ Keys[edges];
    KeySort @ a
  ]

allConnected[edges]
```

> ```
> <|1 -> {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 2 -> {4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 3 -> {5, 8, 9, 10}, 
>  4 -> {9, 10}, 5 -> {10}, 6 -> {7, 8, 9, 10}, 7 -> {8, 9, 10}, 8 -> {9, 10},
>  9 -> {10}, 10 -> {}|>
> ```

```
allConnected[edges] ~Lookup~ {6, 4}
```

> ```
> {{7, 8, 9, 10}, {9, 10}}
> ```

Comment: +1. But note that your solution goes into an infinite loop, when processing loops in a graph.

Comment: @Leonid oops.  Did I fix it?

Comment: Looks like you did. Very elegant solution. It deserves more upvotes, in my view.

Comment: @Leonid thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Adapting [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7621/125) for finding the transitive closure of a symmetric binary relation (and dropping the symmetry property):

```
 edges = {1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 6 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 
 8 -> 9, 9 -> 10, 6 -> 10, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 9, 5 -> 10};  

 pairs = edges /. Rule -> List;
 m = Max@pairs;
 (*the adjacency matrix of atomic elements in pairs:*)
 SparseArray[pairs~Append~{i_, i_} -> 1, {m, m}];
 (* find the transitive closure:*)
 Normal@Sign@MatrixPower[N@%, m];
 (* find labels of reachable vertices  *)
 Join @@ Position[#, 1] & /@ %
 (*==> {{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 
  {3, 5, 8, 9, 10}, {4, 9, 10}, {5, 10}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 
  {7, 8, 9, 10}, {8, 9, 10}, {9, 10}, {10}}  *)
 (* organize: *)
 Grid[{First@#, Rest@#} & /@ %, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]

Note: As is, this works for cases where the vertex list is a range of contigous integers. For a general graph `g` where vertex list is an arbitrary set, one can work with the set of vertex indices `VertexIndex[g,#]&/@VertexList[g]`.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way using `GraphDistanceMatrix`:

```
edges = {1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 6 -> 7, 7 -> 8,
8 -> 9, 9 -> 10, 6 -> 10, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 9, 5 -> 10};
```

If

```
mygraph = Graph@edges;
vertex = VertexList@mygraph;
graphdist = GraphDistanceMatrix@mygraph;
```

then

```
{vertex, Pick[##, Except[_List | Infinity | 0]] & @@@ 
     Thread[{vertex, graphdist}, List, {2}]} // Transpose // Sort // Column
```

returns

```
{1,{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}}
{2,{4,5,7,8,9,10}}
{3,{5,8,9,10}}
{4,{9,10}}
{5,{10}}
{6,{7,8,9,10}}
{7,{8,9,10}}
{8,{9,10}}
{9,{10}}
{10,{}}
```