# Happy 2K prime question

Tags: performance-tuning, prime-numbers

This being the Q number 2K in the site, and this being the day we got the confirmation of mathematica.se graduating soon, I think a celebration question is in order.

So...

What is the fastest way to compute the [happy prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number#Happy_primes) number 2000 in Mathematica?

**Edit**

Here are the **Timing[ ]** results so far:

```
 {"JM",      {5.610, 137653}}
 {"Leonid",  {5.109, {12814, 137653}}}
 {"wxffles", {4.11, {12814, 137653}}}
 {"Rojo",    {0.765, {12814, 137653}}}
 {"Rojo1",   {0.547, {12814, 137653}}}
```

Comment: You should offer a 2K bounty to celebrate

Comment: @Rojo A bounty can't be started until a few days after the Q was posted

Comment: We can extend the celebration :)

Comment: You tested the boringer simpler version of my edit?

Comment: Not yet, testing right now

Comment: By the way, weren't you about a month ago making Mr.Wizard repeat "I will not use AbsoluteTiming to measure timings"? Hehe

Comment: @Rojo I still believe that, but the first timings in the answers were done with it, and I did not want to start an argument. I am modifying the result table in that direction, since it does not affect the results

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This answer should be read upside down, since the last edit has the fastest, neatest and shortest answer

```
Module[{$guard = True},

happyQ[i_] /; $guard := Block[{$guard = False, appeared},
   appeared[_] = False;
   happyQ[i]
   ]
 ]

e : happyQ[_?appeared] := e = False;

happyQ[1] = True;

e : happyQ[i_] := e = (appeared[i] = True; happyQ[#.#&@IntegerDigits[i]])
```

Now, taking this from @LeonidShiffrin

```
happyPrimeN[n_] := Module[{m = 0, pctr = 0},
   While[m < n, If[happyQ@Prime[++pctr], m++]];
   {pctr, Prime[pctr]}];
```

**EDIT**

Ok, this was cool, but if you don't mind wasting a little memory and not resetting `appeared`, it becomes simple and less cool

```
appeared[_] = False;
happyQ[1] = True;
happyQ[_?appeared] = False;
e : happyQ[i_] := e = (appeared[i] = True; happyQ[#.# &@IntegerDigits[i]])
```

**EDIT2**

Slightly faster but I like it twice as much

```
happyQ[1] = True;
e : happyQ[i_] := (e = False; e = happyQ[#.# &@IntegerDigits[i]])
```

or perhaps to make it slightly shorter and a little bit more memory efficient, reducing the recursion tree's height

```
happyQ[1] = True;
e : happyQ[i_] := e = happyQ[e = False; #.# &@IntegerDigits[i]]
```

Comment: Chagracia! Para vos también @belisarius. +1 to the question!

Comment: Speedy!  And in the best traditions, obfuscated too.

Comment: This is very cool!+1

Comment: You got an extra ^2 after `IntegerDigits` in your first solution.  I just realized my solution is exactly the same as your except it's written in a much more boring way.

Comment: Edit 2 is awesome!

Comment: Thanks @SimonWoods, I really like it too :)! I was thinking about something totally unrelated and it popped in my head. Btw, nice domain coloring image

Comment: Rojo I'm curious, have you seen [this?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4844/121)

Comment: No @MrWizard. I see I wasn't the first to come up with that idea ;). I have to leave now but in about 2 hours I'll look at it more carefully. Graphs are my week spot so I will need more than a minute. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Rojo I'm sure I wasn't the first either.  Your last form above is really beautiful in its simplicity.  I thought you might find another application of a somewhat similar recursion interesting.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, definately interested. I'm looking at it. It seems that elegant trick served exactly the same purpose. That's great code, +1!

Answer (score 13):

This probably counts as cheating, since it uses the fact that all unhappy numbers end up in a cycle including 4. But I like it for simplicity...

```
happyQ[1]=True;
happyQ[4]=False;
happyQ[n_]:=happyQ[n]=happyQ[#.#&@IntegerDigits[n]]
```

This works with Leonid's `happyPrimeN` function.

Comment: +1 and happy 2K, Simon. I'll include the timing later (need to work now)

Comment: Can you prove that this is the case?  **EDIT** There's a proof on Wikipedia.

Comment: @Szabolcs: there's a proof [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2304639).

Comment: Hehe, can't fight knowledge with brute force. +1!

Answer (score 12):

#### Simple top-level solution

Here is a simplistic completely top-level code:

```
ClearAll[happyQ];
happyQ[n_] :=
  Block[{appeared},
    appeared[_] = False;
    Take[
       NestWhileList[
          Total[IntegerDigits[#]^2] &,
          n,
          (! appeared[#] && (appeared[#] = True)) &
       ], -2] == {1, 1}];

Clear[happyPrimeN];
happyPrimeN[n_] :=
  Module[{m = 0, pctr = 0},
    While[m < n, If[happyQ@Prime[++pctr], m++]];
    {pctr, Prime[pctr]}
  ];
```

Using this, we get for example:

```
happyPrimeN/@Range[5]

(* {{4,7},{6,13},{8,19},{9,23},{11,31}}  *)
```

And for 2000th happy prime, we have:

```
happyPrimeN[2000] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {1.5693359, {12814, 137653}}  *)
```

which is not particularly fast, but probably ok. I am sure that there are faster solutions though.

#### Java solution with memoization

One thing I want to mention here: I had about 10 iterations of this one before I finally optimized it, and when I did, I looked closer at @Rojo's solution and found that I just arrived to a Java port of it. So, while I did it independently, I just want to stress that the following code does not contain new or better ideas than those used by @Rojo for his beautiful solution.

Ok, so:

1. Load the [Java reloader](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/looking-for-longest-common-substring-solution/6376#6376)
2. Compile the following class:

   ```
   JCompileLoad@"import java.util.*;

       public class HappyPrimes{   
           public Map<Integer,Boolean> happy = new HashMap<Integer,Boolean>(10000);
           private int max;

           public HappyPrimes(int max){
                this.max = max;
                happy.put(1,true); 
           }

           public  int getDigitsSqSum(int num){
               int result = 0;
               while(num>0){
                   int dig = num % 10;
                   result+=dig*dig;
                   num /=10;
               }       
               return  result;
           }

           private boolean isHappy(int num){
               if(happy.containsKey(num)){
                   return happy.get(num);
               }
               happy.put(num,false);
               boolean result  = isHappy(getDigitsSqSum(num));
               happy.put(num,result);
               return result;
           }

           public  int[] currentMaxHappyPrime(int[] primes,
                              int startPrime, int currentMax){
               int done = 0;               
               int i = 0;      
               for( ; i< primes.length ; i++){     
                    if(isHappy(primes[i])&& ++currentMax == max){
                         done = 1;
                         break;
                    }                                          
               }
               startPrime+=i;
               return new int[]{startPrime,currentMax,done};
           } 
       }";
   ```
3. The "top-level" function follows:

   ```
   ClearAll[happyPrimeNJ];
   happyPrimeNJ[n_, chunk_: 5000] :=
     JavaBlock[
        With[{o = JavaNew["HappyPrimes", n]},
          {#, Prime[#]} &@(First[#] + 1) &@
             NestWhile[
                o@currentMaxHappyPrime[
                    Prime[Range[First@# + 1, First@# + chunk]], #[[1]], #[[2]]
                ] &,
                {0, 0, 0},
                Last@# != 1 &]
        ]
     ];
   ```

What happens here is that I use Mathematica to generate primes in chunks. I send those to Java and count the number of happy primes in a given chunk. When I get enough, I stop and return the prime index. At intermediate steps, I return a list of 3 numbers: current total number of processed primes, current total number of happy primes among those, and a flag telling me whether or not I should continue.

Here is how we use it:

```
happyPrimeNJ[50000]//AbsoluteTiming

{1.2324219,{365523,5263169}}
```

My benchmarks show that it is systematically several times (up to 10) faster than @Rojo's version, but we don't see a dramatic speed-up as in some other cases, since @Rojo very cleverly uses the language, and Mathematica hash tables (`DownValues`) are pretty efficient. Also, for (relatively) small numbers of happy primes (such as 2000), the speedup is not so apparent since there is a constant overhead of Java calls which is of the same order as the total time it takes to process those.

#### Summary and conclusions

The first method I presented is relatively slow, being the most straightforward. The second one, based on Java, is fast. However, it does not really compete with the elegant and terse solution of @Rojo, and moreover, is more or less a direct port of it to Java (even though I arrived at it mostly independently).

Comment: +1 happy 2K, Leonid! As more answers come in, I'll publish benchmarking figures from my machine.

Comment: @belisarius Thanks, and happy 2K for you too! And, I am not done with this yet :)

Comment: Due to some problems in my JVM setup, I can't test your last version. As this is now CW, you may go on and edit the scoring section of the Q with the relevant info. Sorry!

Comment: @belisarius No problem :) I will edit the scoring section when I get some time. B.t.w., what platform are you in? The reloader should work out of the box, because it uses the JVM which comes bundled with Mathematica. So if it doesn't, I want to know about it, so I can see what the problem is, and fix it.

Comment: My problem with the JVM is just because I mixed up the bundled one with my own while playing a little. Nothing serious, but I have to reinstall a few things before both of them can work properly :(

Comment: @belisarius Oh, I see. I try to not touch the bundled one, it is not a standard JRE (e.g. it includes a compiler, which is normally not the case for JRE, you need JDK for that).

Answer (score 11):

```
Clear[happyPrimeN];
happyPrimeN[2000] = 137653;

happyPrimeN[2000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0., 137653}`

But seriously, here's a memoised, recursive happyQ that can be used with Leonid's happyPrimeN

```
Clear[sos, happyQ];
sos[k_Integer] := sos[k] = #.# &[IntegerDigits[k]];
happyQ[k_Integer] := happyQ[k] = happyQ[k, {}];
happyQ[1, history_List] := True;
happyQ[k_Integer, history_List] := 
   With[{h = sos[k]}, If[MemberQ[history, h], False, happyQ[h, Prepend[history, h]]]];

happyPrimeN[2000] // AbsoluteTiming
happyPrimeN[2000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{1.4531250, {12814, 137653}}`
>
> `{0.0468750, {12814, 137653}}`

Comment: Note: `Total[IntegerDigits[#]^2]` is faster than my silly `Plus @@ (#^2 & /@ IntegerDigits[k])`, but I can't steal all of Leonid's code.  I always forget about `Listable`.

Comment: C'mon, don't be ashamed! This is for fun!

Comment: If you really wanted an alternative: `sos[k_Integer] := Norm[IntegerDigits[k]]^2`.

Comment: You just made me look for an alternative to `Total[IntegerDigits[#]^2]`, and since what I found seems to be faster than that one, I used it myself, hehe. But I hereby, on the record, grant you the exclusive license to use it `#.#&[IntegerDigits[#]]`

Comment: @Rojo I was wondering when someone would get around to `#.#&[..]`

Answer (score 10):

Here's my take:

```
(* Brent's algorithm for cycle detection *)
happyQ[start_Integer] := Module[{cyc, f, hare, pow, tortoise},
       f = Total[IntegerDigits[#]^2] &;
       cyc = pow = 1;
       tortoise = start; hare = f[start];
       While[tortoise =!= hare,
             If[pow == cyc,
                tortoise = hare; pow *= 2; cyc = 0;];
             hare = f[hare];
             cyc++];
       cyc === 1]

happyPrimeN[1] = 7;
happyPrimeN[n_Integer] := happyPrimeN[n] = 
  Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity}, 
   NestWhile[NextPrime, happyPrimeN[n - 1], (! happyQ[#] &), {2, 1}]]
```

Comment: @bel: confetti and alcohol is in order indeed. :)

Answer (score 9):

Here is my method (not sure it counts):

```
happyPrimeN = Import["http://oeis.org/A035497/b035497.txt", "table"][[#, 2]] &

happyPrimeN[2000] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[14]= {0.7490428, 137653}
```

Comment: Hehe ... I have a veeeery slow Internet connection :D

Answer (score 6):

a short functional style solution:

```
HappyQ[n_Integer?Positive] := NestWhile[
    Total[IntegerDigits[#]^2] &, n,
    Unequal,
    All
  ] == 1
NextHappyPrime[n_Integer?Positive] := NestWhile[
    NextPrime,
    NextPrime[n],
    Composition[Not, HappyQ]
  ]
HappyPrimeN[n_Integer?Positive] := Nest[NextHappyPrime, 7, n - 1]

HappyPrimeN[2000]
```

Comment: Elegant! +1 and happy 2K whatever that means

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: After reading the other answers, this seems to be the same as Rojo's method, except written in a less interesting way.

---

Here's my shot at the problem.  I didn't look at the other solutions to keep this more fun (it's community wiki anyway).

```
happyQ;

Begin["happyQ`"];

happyQ[num_] :=
 Block[{seenQ},
  seenQ[_] = False;
  isHappy[num]
  ]

propagate = Total[IntegerDigits[#]^2] &;

isHappy[1] = True;

isHappy[num_] :=
 If[seenQ[num],
  False,
  seenQ[num] = True;
  isHappy[num] = isHappy[propagate[num]]
  ]

End[];


happyPrimeN[n_Integer] :=
 Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity, count, p},
  count = 0;
  p = 1;
  While[count < 2000,
   p = NextPrime[p];
   While[! happyQ[p], p = NextPrime[p]];
   count++
   ];
  p
 ]
```

I get a timing of 0.8 seconds on this machine.

Comment: Okay, looking at other solutions, nothing new here.  But it was fun :-)

Comment: +1, interesting scoping.

Comment: No matter how it is written, it is a cool method. +1.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty late to the party but here's my attempt:

It involves grabbing a dynamic amount of primes at a time and testing.

```
happyQ[1] = True;
happyQ[4] = False;
happyQ[n_] := happyQ[n] = happyQ[Total[IntegerDigits[n]^2]]

happyPrime[n_] := iHappyPrime[n, 0]

iHappyPrime[n_, s_] := With[{primes = Select[Range[s, NextPrime[s, n]], PrimeQ]},
    With[{count = Count[primes, v_ /; happyQ[v]]},
        If[count < n,
            iHappyPrime[n - count, Last[primes] + 1],
            Select[primes, happyQ][[n]]
        ]
    ]
]

In[1]:= happyPrime[2000] // Timing

Out[1]= {0.479137, 137653}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm very late here, but why not?

First I steal the list of happy numbers below 1000 from wikipedia:

```
happy1000 = {1, 7, 10, 13, 19, 23, 28, 31, 32, 44, 49, 68, 70, 79, 82,
   86, 91, 94, 97, 100, 103, 109, 129, 130, 133, 139, 167, 176, 188, 
  190, 192, 193, 203, 208, 219, 226, 230, 236, 239, 262, 263, 280, 
  291, 293, 301, 302, 310, 313, 319, 320, 326, 329, 331, 338, 356, 
  362, 365, 367, 368, 376, 379, 383, 386, 391, 392, 397, 404, 409, 
  440, 446, 464, 469, 478, 487, 490, 496, 536, 556, 563, 565, 566, 
  608, 617, 622, 623, 632, 635, 637, 638, 644, 649, 653, 655, 656, 
  665, 671, 673, 680, 683, 694, 700, 709, 716, 736, 739, 748, 761, 
  763, 784, 790, 793, 802, 806, 818, 820, 833, 836, 847, 860, 863, 
  874, 881, 888, 899, 901, 904, 907, 910, 912, 913, 921, 923, 931, 
  932, 937, 940, 946, 964, 970, 973, 989, 998, 1000};
```

Then I set `DownValues` for `happyQ`

```
Do[happyQ[n] = True, {n, happy1000}];
Do[happyQ[n] = False, {n, Complement[Range[1000], happy1000]}];
happyQ[n_Integer] := happyQ[#.#&@IntegerDigits[n]]
```

And finally I output the list of `2` and the first 2000 happy primes:

```
NestList[NestWhile[NextPrime, NextPrime[#], Not@*happyQ] &, 2, 2000]
```

or more briefly I do

```
Nest[NestWhile[NextPrime, NextPrime[#], Not@*happyQ] &, 2, 2000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.216036, 137653}
> ```

Undoubtedly, since three years ago execution speed must have improved.