# Comparing the last output of a nested function with all the previous ones

Tags: functions

my main question is how I can compare the last output of a nested function with all the previous ones and stop iterating when I find a repeating value. (I have 2 other questions but I think they are so simple that they do not deserve a separate topic, so I'll post them here).

For example, let's say I want to see if a number is happy or not (I got the idea from a recent topic) and look at all the iterations. Here is the code I wrote

```
f = NestWhileList[Total @ (#^2 & @ IntegerDigits[#]) &, #, !(# == 1 || # == 4) &] &
```

for `f@309` I get

```
{309, 90, 81, 65, 61, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4}
```

I wrote that code because I know that the list will eventually reach 1 or 4. What if I didn't? Let's say I know only that the list will reach a cycle, but the numbers can change. How can I compare the last iteration with all the others and stop when I find a number repeated? In this case the list should stop at

```
{309, 90, 81, 65, 61, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, 16, 37}
```

because 37 is already there.

**Subquestion 1.**

`f @ {309,21}` don't work, I have to write `f /@ {309,21}`. I thought that pure functions were listable, like `#^3 &`, why is f not? Has it something to do with Nest?

**Subquestion 2.**

It's a little question about pure functions, what's the difference between `f := #^2 &` and `f = #^2 &`?

**EDIT 2**

Thank you for the answers, if someone is curious, here is a timing test on my computer. Naming

```
(* Leonid *)
f1[n_] := Module[{appeared}, appeared[_] = False;
   NestWhileList[Total[IntegerDigits[#]^2] &, 
    n, (! appeared[#] && (appeared[#] = True)) &]];
(* Belisarius/WReach *)
f2 = NestWhileList[Total@(#^2 &@IntegerDigits[#]) &, #, Unequal, 
    All] &;
(* j.Vincent *)
f3 = NestWhile[Append[#, Total@(#^2 &@IntegerDigits[#[[-1]]])] &, {#},
     Length[Union[#]] == Length[#] &] &;
f4 = Block[{continue}, (continue[a_] := (continue[a] = False; True);
     NestWhileList[Total@(#^2 &@IntegerDigits[#]) &, #, continue])] &;
(* image_doctor *)
f5 = FixedPoint[
    DeleteDuplicates@
      Append[#, Total@(#^2 &@IntegerDigits[#]) & @ Last[#]] &, {#}] &;
(* WReach *)
nestUntilCycle[f_, x_] := 
  Module[{fast = x, more = True}, 
   NestWhile[f, f@x, (fast = f@f@fast; # != fast) &]; 
   NestWhileList[(If[more, fast = f@fast]; f@#) &, 
    x, # != fast || more && (more = False; True) &]];
(* Mr.Wizard *)
f6 = Module[{in}, 
    in[x_] := (in[x] = "Exit"; Total[IntegerDigits[x]^2]);
    Most@NestWhileList[in, #, # =!= "Exit" &]] &;
f7 = NestWhileList[Total[IntegerDigits[#]^2] &, #, 
    Signature@{##} =!= 0 &, All] &;
```

I obtained

```
AbsoluteTiming[f1 /@ Range[1, 25000];]
AbsoluteTiming[f2 /@ Range[1, 25000];]
AbsoluteTiming[f3 /@ Range[1, 25000];]
AbsoluteTiming[f4 /@ Range[1, 25000];]
AbsoluteTiming[f5 /@ Range[1, 25000];]
AbsoluteTiming[nestUntilCycle[Total@(#^2 &@IntegerDigits[#]) &, #] & /@ Range[1,25000];]
AbsoluteTiming[f6 /@ Range[1, 25000];]
AbsoluteTiming[f7 /@ Range[1, 25000];]

{3.0888054, Null}
{1.7004030, Null}
{2.6676047, Null}
{2.5740045, Null}
{1.9500035, Null}
{5.6784099, Null}
{2.9640052, Null}
{2.6520046, Null}
```

Time was not an issue, I included it only for completeness. 
Note: as Leonid and others pointed out, in this case the differences are negligible, but with longer lists and cycles it is better to avoid methods with quadratic complexity.

Let's use the function proposed by Mr.Wizard and see what changes

```
f0 = Mod[# + 1, 2000] &;
(* Leonid *)
f1[n_] := Module[{appeared}, appeared[_] = False;
   NestWhileList[f0, n, (! appeared[#] && (appeared[#] = True)) &]];
(* Belisarius/WReach *)
f2 = NestWhileList[f0, #, Unequal, All] &;
(* j.Vincent *)
f3 = NestWhile[Append[#, f0[#[[-1]]]] &, {#}, 
    Length[Union[#]] == Length[#] &] &;
f4 = Block[{continue}, (continue[a_] := (continue[a] = False; True);
     NestWhileList[f0, #, continue])] &;
(* image_doctor *)
f5 = FixedPoint[DeleteDuplicates@Append[#, f0 @ Last[#]] &, {#}] &;
(* WReach *)
nestUntilCycle[f_, x_] := 
  Module[{fast = x, more = True}, 
   NestWhile[f, f@x, (fast = f@f@fast; # != fast) &]; 
   NestWhileList[(If[more, fast = f@fast]; f@#) &, 
    x, # != fast || more && (more = False; True) &]];
(* Mr.Wizard *)
f6 = Module[{in}, in[x_] := (in[x] = "Exit"; f0[x]);
    Most@NestWhileList[in, #, # =!= "Exit" &]] &;
f7 = NestWhileList[f0, #, Signature@{##} =!= 0 &, All] &;
```

On my pc

```
AbsoluteTiming[f1@ 0;]
AbsoluteTiming[f2@ 0;]
AbsoluteTiming[f3@ 0;]
AbsoluteTiming[f4@ 0;]
AbsoluteTiming[f5@ 0;]
AbsoluteTiming[nestUntilCycle[f0, #] & @0;]
AbsoluteTiming[f6@ 0;]
AbsoluteTiming[f7@ 0;]

{0.0110007, Null}
{17.0559755, Null}
{0.0940053, Null}
{0.0080004, Null}
{0.0160010, Null}
{0.0150008, Null}
{0.0100006, Null}
{0.3420196, Null}
```

Calling out `f2` and trying with `f0 = Mod[# + 1, 20000] &` these are the results

```
{0.1140065, Null}
{8.9305108, Null}
{0.0840048, Null}
{0.9790560, Null}
{0.1470084, Null}
{0.1040060, Null}
{55.5261759, Null}
```

Comment: I think that [that question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7132/happy-2k-prime-question) you mentioned provides good solutions to the problem (particularly one by @Rojo). If you insist on `NestWhile(List)`, my solution there uses it. The problem with currently posted answers based on `Append` is that `Append`-based accumulation method has a quadratic complexity in the size of the iteration results, and that sort or destroys the purpose of `NestWhile(List)`.

Comment: Yeah, in fact I used your function in the edit, with Module instead of Block, but I still don't get it. When does appeard[] change to True?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin isn't the quadratic scaling actually required in this case? I mean you wouldn't be able to carry out calculations based on the past inputs to the function unless you somehow pass them along.

Comment: @jVincent That depends. You can, for example, store those in a hash table (like I did, in a way), linked list, some tree, etc. Storing them in a linked list, for instance (which has constant time to add a new element to the end) will replace the problem of efficient inserts to one of efficient access. If it happens that full random access is not needed at each step, one can win big.  But generally, I feel that for such problems the general `NestWhile` abstraction is just not very good, and using data structures optimal for a particular problem (lists, hashes, trees, etc) may be better.

Comment: @JaneT. The test function for `NestWhileList` is `(! appeared[#] && (appeared[#] = True)) &`. Note that the part `(appeared[#] = True)` not just makes the entire value `True`, but also assigns `True` to `appeared[element]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin In this case, you are going to iterate though the entire list every time, so yea, if I was coding a cpp function I would use a linked list, however here it seems that the implementation you are suggesting is actually the slowest, and while you have scoped the function, it's still relying on side effects, which are typically what most people try to avoid when arguing for higher semantics. I would be interested in seeing a faster algorithm based on linked lists implemented in Mathematica, I have no real grasp of how Mathematica relates to lower level code.

Comment: @JaneT. Regarding your benchmarks: note that, for this particular problem, the lists of iteratively produced numbers will never be large, because sum of squares of digits is always hugely smaller than numbers themselves, for large numbers. Therefore, the asymptotic comlexity I was talking about won't show up here. If you just want to solve this particular problem, this is fine, but if you question is about general problems of this type, you may still want to avoid methods which inherently have quadratic complexity.

Comment: @jVincent See my comment to JaneT - my function is only slower because the lists produced by complete iterations are never large for this problem, and symbolic Mathematica overhead hides the complexity for small lists. I was just making a general comment that for this type of problems, the right solution / choice of data structures hugely depends on the access pattern. If you need full random access at every step of the iteration, then yes, there is no way around quadratic complexity. But most problems are not like that, and this one in particular isn't (Rojo's solution and others show that).

Comment: @jVincent As to side effects, I don't see them as inherently evil as long as they are isolated and under control. In this particular case, you can view `appeared[#] = True` as populating a hash-table rather than a side effect, and this is the correct interpretation in the current context. Generally, many algorithms are inherently dependent on side effects, and trying to avoid them at all costs I find a wrong strategy. My point is, separating degrees of abstraction is not the same thing as avoiding side effects, although generally code with more side effects tends to mix those degrees more.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Well my intent was more that I was looking for someway of passing along a linked list (So really a reference) rather then using side effects to populate a hash-table. Is this even possible in Mathematica? Side effects aren't evil, but when arguing code ideology, I would prefer to not having to encapsulate side effects when really I just want a different type of list. That being said, I added a version of your solution to my answer which wins the timing game on my computer at least.

Comment: @jVincent  Yes, sure, you can pass linked lists around. Have a look at `getVertexSequences` function from [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5387/using-mathematicas-graph-functions-to-cheat-at-boggle/5394#5394) for one example. When you pass a linked list, it is not a true pass-by-reference since the new list is also immutable, but it is still passed by reference in the sense that only the top elements (element plus the pointer to the rest of the list) are copied - so we don't pass a reference, but we pass a shallow copy. For the purposes of performance this is ...

Comment: @jVincent ... not so much different, unless you want your passed list to be mutable (which is impossible in this approach). So, you can thing of Mathematica linked lists as "normal" linked lists, but which are immutable (read - only) since you are not given the write access to the pointers to list elements (nodes).

Comment: The last timings should be `f1,f3,f4,f5,nestUntilCycle,f6,f7`. Did I make some mistake? Please correct me if it is so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you only want to compare the output of the function consider just passing along a list as the input to the function, while only operating on the last element. That way each iteration of the function has access to the complete history and the condition as well. Here is an implimentation striving to be as close to your code as possible.

```
f=NestWhile[Append[#, Total@(#^2 &@IntegerDigits[#[[-1]]])] &, {#},
 Length[Union[#]] == Length[#] &] &;
f@309
```

> ```
>    {309, 90, 81, 65, 61, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, 16, 37}
> ```

Since the passed parameter is now the entire list, you still get the outputs from all iterations in the end.

**Subquestion 1.**

Pure functions are not listable, consider the problem that would arise from a pure function given as:

```
 #[[1]]^2+#[[2]]^2&@{1,2}
```

If it was listable per default, this would lead to an error saying that 1[[1]] does not exist. the reason `#^3&` seems listable is because power is Listable.

```
Attributes[Power]
```

> {Listable, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Protected}

**SubQuestion 2.**

Firstly remember that you are not just giving a pure function a name, you are assigning a pure function to a symbol using `Set` and `SetDelayed` the difference is in when the pure function is evaluated. `Set` evaluates once immediately, while `SetDelayed` will evaluate each time the symbol is used. An example of this difference is given in the code below:

```
n = 2;
f1 = Evaluate[#^n] &;
f2 := Evaluate[#^n] &;
n = 3;
f1@2
f2@2
```

> ```
> 4
> 8
> ```

Underling the aspect of `SetDelayed[]` that it is reevaluated whenever it is called. Though Evaluate is needed to force evaluation of n at the time of setting.

**Additional method**

After some discussion with Leonid Shifrin, who's insightfully pointed out that the scaling on this code is very bad for large number of iterations due to the cost associated with appending  in each iteration, I went ahead and wrote a version of his code with wins the timing contest on my setup:

```
f4=Block[{continue},
(continue[a_]:=(continue[a]=False;True);
NestWhileList[Total@(#^2&@IntegerDigits[#])&,#,continue])
]&;

AbsoluteTiming[# /@ Range[1, 25000];][[1]]&/@{f1,f2,f3,f4}(*f1-3 are defined in the question*)
```

> {3.5937500, 3.6093750, 2.9687500, 2.9218750}

Though it's only bairly faster, it should scale much better for arbitrary testing functions. I believe the difference in timing is due to `Block` vs. `Module`, though it also avoids some Boolean operations.

Comment: Good answers, thank you very much. So, for practical purposes, f := #^2 & and f = #^2 & are the same, since there is nothing that can change in successive evaluation (like n in your example)... am I right?

Comment: @Jane T. I would suspect that unless Mathematica knows to optimize away the repeated calls to the definition that f:=#^2& would be unnecessarily slower. On my system the timings when calling Table[f@i, {i, 10^6}] are 1.25 for f=#^2& and 1.45 for f:=#^2&, so while there is no difference in the results it appears that there is a difference in the way you arrive at the results. I would suggest always using set in cases such as this where the definition isn't supposed to be reevaluated at every call.

Comment: Compare your timings with the solution suggested by @WReach in the comments under my question `f5 = NestWhileList[f0, #, Unequal, All] &;` (30% faster)

Answer (score 15):

There is an [old trick](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node149.html) used by many LISP implementations to deal with circular lists.  That trick is based upon [Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) and could be adapted to the task at hand.

Here is `nestUntilCycle`, a function similar to `Nest` except that it stops when it detects a value that has been seen before:

```
nestUntilCycle[f_, x_] :=
  Module[{fast = x, more = True}
  , NestWhile[f, f @ x, (fast = f @ f @ fast; # != fast) &]
  ; NestWhileList[
      (If[more, fast = f @ fast]; f @ #) &
    , x
    , # != fast || more && (more = False; True) &
    ]
  ]
```

This implementation is less self-evident than some of the other answers to this question (for me, at least), but it has the advantage that it runs in near linear time and uses a constant amount of additional working storage.  In particular, it neither searches through all the predecessors of each value (quadratic run-time), nor does it keep any auxiliary memoization data or hash tables.

Following Floyd, the function examines the generated sequence of values by means of two "pointers", a "slow" pointer that visits every value and a "fast" pointer that only visits every second value.  If the sequence contains a cycle, then the fast pointer must eventually land on the same element as the slow pointer.  After that, some tricky sequence traversals can identify both the lead-in to the cycle and the cycle itself.  See the Wikipedia reference for the niggly details.  If the sequence does not contain a cycle, then the CPU will get hot but no result will ever be generated.  It is left as an exercise to the reader to add other `Nest`-like features such as an optional iteration limit count to handle non-cyclic sequences.

Note that this implementation will only work for functions in the mathematical sense: functions that generate exactly one result for any given input.

We can use the "happy number" computation to test out `nestUntilCycle`:

```
h[n_] := IntegerDigits[n] ^ 2 // Total

nestUntilCycle[h, 1]
(* {1, 1} *)

nestUntilCycle[h, 4]
(* {4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4} *)

nestUntilCycle[h, 61]
(* {61, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, 16, 37} *)

nestUntilCycle[h, 309]
(* {309, 90, 81, 65, 61, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, 16, 37} *)
```

**Visualization**

The code below creates a crude visualization of `nestUntilCycle` in operation.  One can press the *Step* button repeatedly to watch how the "slow" and "fast" pointers progress through the sequence and how the result is built up.

[image: Visualization Screenshot]

The code requires the definitions of `nestUntilCycle` and `h` from above.

```
DynamicModule[{start, graph, draw, vertex, state, ptr, step, phase, reset}
, start = 309
; graph = Rule @@@ Partition[nestUntilCycle[h, start], 2, 1]
; reset[] := state = {1, h @ start, h @ h @ start, {}}
; vertex[pos_, n_] :=
    Inset[
      Column[
        { ptr["slow", n, state[[2]]]
        , Framed[n, Background -> LightYellow]
        , ptr["fast", n, state[[3]]]
        }
      ]
    , pos
    ]
; ptr[label_, a_, a_] := Style[label, {Bold, Larger}]
; ptr[_, _, _] := ""
; step[{1, n_, n_, r_}] := {2, start, n, r}
; step[{1, slow_, fast_, r_}] := {1, h @ slow, h @ h @ fast, r}
; step[{2, slow_, fast_, r_}] := {3, slow, fast, {start}}
; step[{3, n_, n_, {r__}}] := {4, h @ n, n, {r, h @ n}}
; step[{3, slow_, fast_, {r__}}] := {3, h @ slow, h @ fast, {r, h @ slow}}
; step[{4, n_, n_, r_}] := {5, n, n, r}
; step[{4, slow_, fast_, {r__}}] := {4, h @ slow, fast, {r, h @ slow}}
; step[{5, ___}] := reset[]
; phase[{1, n_, n_, _}] := Style["NestWhile loop: slow and fast coincide: cycle found!", Red]
; phase[{1, _, _, _}] := "NestWhile loop: slow advances by 1 value each step, fast advances by 2"
; phase[{2, _, _, _}] := Style["Transitioning to NestWhileListLoop: slow is reset to the start", Red]
; phase[{3, n_, n_, _}] := Style["NestWhileListLoop: slow and fast pointers coincide: cycle start has been found", Red]
; phase[{3, _, _, _}] := "NestWhileListLoop: slow and fast both advance by 1 value each step"
; phase[{4, n_, n_, _}] := Style["NestWhileListLoop: slow and fast coincide: the end of the cycle has been found", Red]
; phase[{4, _, _, _}] := "NestWhileListLoop (more = False): slow (only) traverses the cycle one by one"
; phase[{5, _, _, _}] := Style["DONE!", Red]
; draw[_] :=
    Column[
      { GraphPlot[
          graph
        , VertexRenderingFunction -> vertex
        , DirectedEdges -> True
        , ImageSize -> Full
        ]
      , Row[{Button["Step", state = step[state], ImageSize -> Automatic], phase[state]}, "  "]
      , Row[{"Result So Far: ", Last @ state}]
      }
    , Alignment -> Left
    ]
; reset[]
; Dynamic[draw[state], TrackedSymbols :> {state}]
]
```

Comment: Big +1, this is just brilliant. I feel ashamed since I knew about the pointer trick for loop detection, and yet this did not come to my mind in this context. It took me some time to understand the details of your implementation. The key point you could have mentioned is that `n==L-m mod L`, where `n` is the number of initial steps before we enter the loop, `L` is the length of the loop, and `m` is the position where `fast` ends up after your first `NestWhile`, counted from the start of the loop (I did not bother to read Wikipedia article, perhaps it is there).

Comment: @Leonid Thanks for the feedback.  Instead of trying to explain the slow and fast pointer movement in words, I elected to draw a dynamic picture instead.  Please see the new _Visualization_ section.

Comment: I've seen this method used without explanation on Project Euler.  Thanks for drawing pretty pictures so I finally understand it. **+1**

Comment: For fast functions with long cycles this is a killer method.  However for somewhat slower functions it is slow; do you know if it is possible to modify this method to use *some* caching to reduce the number of function applications before a cycle is detected?  In other words a hybrid method?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Given that we are building a list of the full cyclic sequence, we could retain the values visited by the "slow" pointer on the first pass instead of discarding them and recalculating like `nestUntilCycle` does.  Of course, the more elements we retain, the closer we get to simple memoization.  Memoization is what I would almost certainly use in "real life".  Memoization had already been mentioned in the edited question, but I threw this solution into the mix because all prior solutions needed quadratic time or linear space (linear space is moot, given the result list).

Comment: Okay, suppose we did *not* want to build the entire list, and the goal was: (1) find the element that first repeats, or (2) return only the cycle, or (3) return the length before the cycle and the length of the cycle itself.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard A fixed cache size _C_ retains O(1) space and may yield benefits.  All leader elements and at least half of cycle elements are referenced twice or more for 1), 2) and 3).  If element computation time varies widely, then retaining the top _C_ elements ordered by cost would probably show good benefits.  For relatively uniform computation times, an LRU cache might provide benefit provided _C_ > typical cycle length -- attempting to favour cycle elements which are repeatedly scanned. These examples illustrate how domain-specific knowledge can inform the choice of cache algorithm.

Comment: That is very impressive, thank you very much. I also really liked the visualization method, it shows well how the algorithm works. +1

Comment: @WReach This is really nice. I used some very simplistic visualization of a similar kind (but much simpler) as an aid in understanding the code, but this is so much better.

Comment: Have you tried writing a version that uses Brent's method?

Answer (score 12):

```
f0 = Total@(#^2 &@IntegerDigits[#]) &; (* Your Function *)
f = NestWhileList[f0, #, ! MemberQ[Most@{##}, Last@{##}] &, All] &
f@309
```

> {309, 90, 81, 65, 61, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, 16, 37}

**Edit**

The suggestion made in a comment by @WReach is elegant and improves the performance by a factor of 2.

```
 f = NestWhileList[f0, #, Unequal, All] &
```

Comment: Nice, in my attemps I used ## and Last[##] forgetting the {}.

Comment: @JaneT. Yours is a common mistake. The arguments are provided as a `Sequence[]`. Always remember you can make up the `test` part as `(Print@##;If[...])&` to see what your arguments really are.

Comment: I will remember it, thank you.

Comment: @belisarius 7 seems to be an unhappy number, f@7 ->{7, 49, 97, 130, 10, 1, 1}. All the methods seem to give the repeated 1 at the end, is that a feature ? :)

Comment: @image_doctor the first repeated result is always in the list. In the OP's example it is `37`. In your example it is `1`. What is wrong with that?

Comment: @belisarius Absolutely nothing, I just hadn't noticed that the last element was already in the list or properly read the end of the question, thank you :)

Comment: +1  `f` could be expressed more simply thus: `f = NestWhileList[f0, #, Unequal, All] &`

Comment: @WReach Great! and it is MUCH faster. Edited

Comment: Or, alternatively, `NestWhileList[Total@(#^2 &@IntegerDigits[#]) &, #, UnsameQ, All] & @ 309
`

Answer (score 9):

I haven't worked through the other answers yet, and it appears WReach may have provided the definitive method.  Nevertheless, here are a couple of straightforward ones.

#### Hash table with redefinition

```
f =
 Module[{in},
   in[x_] := (in[x] = "Exit"; Total[IntegerDigits[x]^2]);
   Most@NestWhileList[in, #, # =!= "Exit" &]
 ] &;

f @ 309
```

> ```
> {309, 90, 81, 65, 61, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, 16, 37}
> ```

#### Signature

```
f2 =
  NestWhileList[
    Total[IntegerDigits[#]^2] &,
    #, Signature@{##} =!= 0 &, All
  ] &;

f2 @ 417
```

> ```
> {417, 66, 72, 53, 34, 25, 29, 85, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, 16, 37, 58, 89}
> ```

---

While the method with `Unequal` (from WReach, posted by belisarius) is elegant, it is horrendously inefficient on longer cycles.  `Signature` is faster, and the hash table is much faster still.

```
f0 = Mod[# + 1, 2000] &;

NestWhileList[f0, 0, Unequal, All] // Timing // First

NestWhileList[f0, 0, Signature@{##} =!= 0 &, All] // Timing // First

Module[{in},
  in[x_] := (in[x] = "Exit"; f0[x]);
  Most@NestWhileList[in, 0, # =!= "Exit" &]
] // Timing // First
```

> 15.506
>
> 0.2496
>
> 0.005616

---

Since it is fun to turn this into a speed competition here is my next entry:

```
f3 =
  Block[{hash, test},
    hash = System`Utilities`HashTable[];
    test = System`Utilities`HashTableAdd[hash, #] === Null &;
    NestWhileList[#, #2, test] // Quiet
  ] &;

f3[Mod[# + 1, 1*^6] &, 0] // Length // Timing
```

> {1.763, 1000001}

Comment: Very fast indeed, thank you for the examples.

Comment: @Jane I added another method for you to try.  Thanks for doing the speed testing; it makes this fun. :-)

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't quite strictly meet the specifications of the original question, but its close and offers slightly different approach which might be appropriate in some circumstances.

Borrowing from Belisarius's answer:

```
f10 = Total@(#^2 &@IntegerDigits[#]) &;

f11 = DeleteDuplicates@Append[#, f10[Last@#]] &

FixedPoint[f11, {309}]
```

> {309, 90, 81, 65, 61, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, 16}

As you can see it omits the last, repeated, element of the list but does terminate when a duplicate is detected and utilises `FixedPoint` in place of `NestWhile`.

Timings were as follows:

```
AbsoluteTiming[f1 /@ Range[1, 25000];]
AbsoluteTiming[f2 /@ Range[1, 25000];]
AbsoluteTiming[f3 /@ Range[1, 25000];]
AbsoluteTiming[FixedPoint[f11, {#}] & /@ Range[1, 25000];]
```

> {1.824699, Null}
>
> {1.602500, Null}
>
> {1.513778, Null}
>
> {1.247677, Null}

Answer (score 3):

Ugly but answers the first question :

```
ugly = NestWhileList[{Append[#[[1]], #[[2]]], Function[x, Total[(#^2 & /@ IntegerDigits[x])]][#[[2]]]} &, {{}, 309}, ! MemberQ[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &] ;

ugly[[All, 2]]

(* {309,90,81,65,61,37,58,89,145,42,20,4,16,37} *)
```