# Partition a list into sublists of different lengths

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the list `{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}`  and I want to make a sub-list of the form `{{{a, b}, c}, {{d, e}, f}, {{g, h}, i}}`
I've tried using [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html), but I can't see how to use it here.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. [Your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), but its a good idea to wait 24hours for other answers before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you.

Comment: When you see good questions and answers, please vote them up by clicking the grey triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. As you receive help, try to give it too, by *answering questions* in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good problem for the application of argument destructuring.

```
data = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};

restructure[{a_, b_, c_}] := {{a, b}, c}

restructure /@ Partition[data, 3]
```

> ```
> {{{a, b}, c}, {{d, e}, f}, {{g, h}, i}}
> ```

Comment: @LLlAMnYP. Thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: No problem, some of these days I'd sooner believe an obvious typo is actually something real subtle and intended. Say, what's `self : func[args___] := ...` construct called?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP. I don't know any name for that pattern.

Comment: The bot bumped this post today: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7136/26956 - saw it in the last two lines of code. Your typo reminded me of that. A couple of minutes for chat, maybe?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP. Sorry, can't chat -- late in my time zone -- need to sign out.

Comment: I really like this answer as for a novice- it is easy to understand- many thanks!!

Comment: @TerenceCosgrove If you feel it's the best one for you, please do accept it. But for interpolation of functions with multidimensional variables the general form is `{{{args1},f1},{{args2},f2},...}` in that case, a solution that's general enough for any number of elements, not just 3 would suit you better.

Answer (score 14):

My take:

```
{Most@#, Last@#} & /@ Partition[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, 3]
```

@Guesswhoitis:

```
Transpose[{Drop[#, None, -1], #[[All, -1]]}] & @ Partition[list, 3]
```

@Pickett

```
Developer`PartitionMap[{Most[#], Last[#]} &, lst, 3]
```

Comment: Equivalent: `Transpose[{Drop[#, None, -1], #[[All, -1]]}] & @ Partition[list, 3]`.

Comment: @J. M. True... but for what purpose? (I mean, faster, or something else?)

Comment: It can also be written ``Developer`PartitionMap[{Most[#], Last[#]} &, lst, 3]``, which might be faster.

Comment: @Pickett Oooh, regardless, how similar to normal built-in functions, this should be an answer.

Comment: I just presented an approach that is not very different (which is why I left a comment and not an answer).

Answer (score 11):

Using the (undocumented) six-argument form of `Partition`  to restructure partition elements:

```
Partition[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, 3, 3, 1, {}, {{#, #2}, #3} &]
```

> {{{a, b}, c}, {{d, e}, f}, {{g, h}, i}}

Also

```
SequenceCases[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, {a_, b_, c_}:>{{a, b}, c}]
```

> {{{a, b}, c}, {{d, e}, f}, {{g, h}, i}}

Answer (score 9):

For those with 10.2, a couple new functions for the heck of it...

```
BlockMap[TakeDrop[#, 2] /. {l_} :> l &, list, 3]
```

or

```
BlockMap[TakeDrop[#, 2]~FlattenAt~2 &, list, 3]
```

or

```
With[{k := {{#1, #2}, #3} &}, BlockMap[k @@ # &, list, 3]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Yet another one for variety:

```
dat = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};

{Partition[dat, 2, 3], dat[[3 ;; ;; 3]]}\[Transpose]
```

> ```
> {{{a, b}, c}, {{d, e}, f}, {{g, h}, i}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Something with rules:

```
Partition[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, 3] /. {x_, y_, z_?AtomQ} -> {{x, y}, z}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};

BlockMap[Apply[{{#1, #2}, #3} &], list, 3]
```

{{{a, b}, c}, {{d, e}, f}, {{g, h}, i}}

Comment: (+1) Also `BlockMap[{Most@#,Last@#}&, list, 3]`

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};
Partition[Riffle[Partition[#, 2, 3], Take[#, {3, -1, 3}]], 2] &@list
```

> {{{a, b}, c}, {{d, e}, f}, {{g, h}, i}}

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `MapApply` and `Partition`:

```
{Most@{##}, #3} & @@@ Partition[#, 3] &@list

(*{{{a, b}, c}, {{d, e}, f}, {{g, h}, i}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `TakeList`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];

f[k_List, parts_List] := Module[{tp = Total@parts},
  FoldPairList[{TakeList[#1, parts], #1[[tp + 1 ;;]]} &
    , k
    , ConstantArray[1, Quotient[Length@k, tp]]] //
   Map[FlattenAt[-1]]
  ]
```

*Usage*

```
alist = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};
f[alist, {2, 1}]
```

> {{{a, b}, c}, {{d, e}, f}, {{g, h}, i}}

```
f[Alphabet[], {5, 3}]
```

> {{{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}, "f", "g",    "h"}, {{"i", "j", "k", "l",
> "m"}, "n", "o",    "p"}, {{"q", "r", "s", "t", "u"}, "v", "w", "x"}}

```
f[Alphabet[], {2, 2, 1}]
```

> {{{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, "e"}, {{"f", "g"}, {"h", "i"},    "j"},
> {{"k", "l"}, {"m", "n"}, "o"}, {{"p", "q"}, {"r", "s"},    "t"},
> {{"u", "v"}, {"w", "x"}, "y"}}