# How do I map a function pairwise?

Tags: map, functional

Given a list of pairs:

```
data = {{a,b},{c,d},{e,f},{g,h},{i,j}}
```

I need the moving map:

```
MapPair[F,data]
```

> `{ F[{a,b},{c,d}], F[{c,d},{e,f}], F[{e,f},{g,h}], F[{g,h},{i,j}] }`

The built-in function `MovingMap` does not work:

```
MovingMap[F,data,2]
```

Which built-in function does maps a function `F` pairwise over the data?

Comment: I need a built-in function that essentially does this: `myMapPair[func_, data_] := 
 Array[func[data[[#1]], data[[#1 + 1]]] &, Length[data] - 1]`

Comment: `BlockMap[F, data, 2, 1]` ought to work.

Comment: I like the BlockMap idea.    You can also try     mapPair[f_, v_] := f @@@ Partition[ v, 2, 1]

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks! I knew it had to exist!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
BlockMap[Apply[F], data, 2, 1]
```

Comment: i usually use mapthread when i have multiple variables but i knew there had to be a shorter more robust MMA "blackbelt" configuration. i havent tried it but assuming this works this should be at the very top and i definitely be using next time i need to break out with sewing needles.

Answer (score 6):

Using `MapAt`:

```
MapAt[Apply[F], Partition[data, {2}, 1], All]
(*{F[{a, b}, {c, d}], F[{c, d}, {e, f}], F[{e, f}, {g, h}], F[{g, h}, {i, j}]}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
MapThread[F, {Most@#, Rest@#}]&[data]

(* {F[{a, b}, {c, d}], F[{c, d}, {e, f}], F[{e, f}, {g, h}], F[{g, h}, {i, j}]} *)
```

In addition, as [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) has pointed out [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165098/106), `Partition` can take an *undocumented* sixth argument.

```
Partition[data,2,1,{1,-1},{},F]

(* {F[{a, b}, {c, d}], F[{c, d}, {e, f}], F[{e, f}, {g, h}], F[{g, h}, {i, j}]} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

2 more possibilities:

```
data = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}, {i, j}};

Most @ MapThread[F, {data, RotateLeft @ data}]
```

{F[{a, b}, {c, d}], F[{c, d}, {e, f}], F[{e, f}, {g, h}], F[{g, h}, {i, j}]}

```
F @@@ Transpose[{data[[;; -2]], data[[2 ;;]]}]
```

{F[{a, b}, {c, d}], F[{c, d}, {e, f}], F[{e, f}, {g, h}], F[{g, h}, {i, j}]}

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of `Partition` can have any `Head`. So we can use

```
List @@ Partition[F @@ data, 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {F[{a, b}, {c, d}], 
>  F[{c, d}, {e, f}],   
>  F[{e, f}, {g, h}],   
>  F[{g, h}, {i, j}]}
> ```

Generalizing:

```
partitionMap = List @@ Partition[# @@ #2, ##3] &;

partitionMap[F, data, 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {F[{a, b}, {c, d}], 
>  F[{c, d}, {e, f}],   
>  F[{e, f}, {g, h}],   
>  F[{g, h}, {i, j}]}
> ```

```
partitionMap[F, data, 3, 1]
```

> ```
>  {F[{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}],   
>   F[{c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}],   
>   F[{e, f}, {g, h}, {i, j}]}
> ```