# Efficiently or Elegantly construct linear graph list from vertex pairs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, algorithm

I am processing [MRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_requirements_planning) data, with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials) relations as pairs of part number strings. I want to construct lists that represent the linear graphs defined by these pairs.

Here is some code to generate random sample data, with real-world distribution of lengths of linear graphs:

```
SeedRandom[1234];

chainLengths = Round /@ RandomVariate[ParetoDistribution[2., 8.], 300];

chainStrings = RandomSample[DictionaryLookup["s" ~~ ___], Total[chainLengths]];

chains = Block[
   {cs = chainStrings},
   Reap[
     Do[
      Sow[cs[[\;\;c]]]; (*remove backslashes, triggers unwanted formatting*)
      cs=cs[[c+1;;]];
      Null,
      {c, chainLengths}
      ]
     ][[2, 1]]
   ];

chainStrings === Flatten[chains]

Out[]= True

Histogram[Length /@ chains]

chainParts = Reap[
    Do[
     Sow[#[[1]] -> #[[2]]] & /@ Partition[c, 2, 1],
     {c, chains}
     ]
    ][[2, 1]];
chainParts = RandomSample[chainParts, Length[chainParts]];
```

And here is my code to construct the linear graph lists from the pair data (fail-fast sanity assertions commented out):

```
buildChains = Block[
   {a, f, p, currentPass, nextPass, fatalError0,},
   (*fatalError0::fatalReport="buildChains fatalError0: `1`";
   fatalError0[msg_]:=(
   Message[fatalError0::fatalReport,ToString[msg]];
   Abort[]
   );*)
   a = {#} & /@ Complement[
      First /@ chainParts, Last /@ chainParts];
   currentPass = chainParts;
   nextPass = {};
   While[Length[currentPass] >= 1,
    Do[
     f = r[[1]];
     p = Position[a, {___, f}];
     If[p === {}, AppendTo[nextPass, r]; Continue[]];
     (*If[{Length[p],Depth[p],LeafCount[p]}=!={1,3,3},
     fatalError0[{"{Length[p],Depth[p],LeafCount[p]}=!={1,3,3}",p}]
     ];*)
     p = p[[1, 1]];
     a[[p]] = Append[a[[p]], r[[2]]],
     {r, currentPass}
     ];
    (*If[currentPass===nextPass,
    Print[a];
    Print[nextPass];
    fatalError0[{"currentPass===nextPass",a,nextPass}]
    ];*)
    currentPass = nextPass;
    nextPass = {}
    ];
   a
   ];

Sort[chains] === Sort[buildChains]

Out[]= True
```

Is there a simpler way to do this with MMA graph functionality? Or more efficient/elegant MMA code, regardless? I imagine the complexity is poor using Position for a linear search.

Comment: Would you mind describing in plain English the logic for how these "chains" are built?

Comment: 1) find heads in pairs that cannot be another's tail 2) pair by pair, use Position to find correct list 3) append to that list

Comment: 4) pairs that are not "ready" to be part of an append get queued for the next pass, or the next, etc

Comment: @Mr.Wizard or do you mean the sample data?

Comment: I only meant what you wrote.  So you want to find all of the connected components of `Graph[chainParts]`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, and the ordering is significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
g = Graph[chainParts];

test = VertexOutComponent[g, #] & /@
    Complement[Keys @ chainParts, Values @ chainParts];

Sort[chains] === Sort[test]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

See: [How to find all vertices reachable from a start vertex following directed edges?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4843/121)

Comment: Amazing! All the graph facilities in MMA boggle my mind, thank goodness there are people like you!

Comment: @Manuel I'm glad I could help. :-)  Make sure to vote for Meng Lu's answer to the linked question as I learned this from him.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming standard BOM structures from MRP Systems.

```
boms = {{"Head", "Component", "Qty"}, {1., 2., 10.}, {1., 3., 
    20.}, {1., 4., 30.}, {2., 5., 10.}, {2., 6., 20.}, {2., 7., 
    30.}, {7., 8., 40.}, {8., 9., 50.}, {9., 10., 60.}, {9., 11., 
    70.}};
partNames = {"Gun", "Body", "Barrel", "Silencer", "Stock", "Lock", 
  "Trigger Kit", "Gizmo A", "Spring", "Cam", "Chunche"}
titles = First@boms; boms = Rest@boms;
TreeGraph[DirectedEdge[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ boms, 
 EdgeWeight -> boms[[All, 3]], 
 VertexLabels -> Thread[N[Range@Length@partNames] -> partNames], 
 GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", ImageSize -> Medium, ImagePadding->Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]