# Conditional subset generation

Tags: performance-tuning, combinatorics

I am trying to accomplish the following task:
Given a list of coordinates of `n` points in the plane, I need to find subsets of all points that share the same x-coordinate OR same y-coordinate.  For instance, for the list:

```
data = {{1,2},{3,1},{1,5},{6,2},{7,3},{4,4},{5,4},{0,0},{2,3},{6,7}}
```

I get:

> ```
> set1 = {{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {6, 2}, {6, 7}}
> set2 = {{0, 0}}
> set3 = {{2, 3}, {7, 3}}
> set4 = {{3, 1}}
> set5 = {{4, 4}, {5, 4}}
> ```

Notice for example in `set1` that `{1, 5}` and `{6, 2}` are in the same set linked indirectly. I have written some "naive implementation" consisting of the two modules shown below. I understand that the use of `Append` is not a good idea.  The code below works, and produces good results for relatively small data sets, but obviously does not scale very well. A data set of 1000 points takes about 150 seconds to run on my computer...

```
findLinks[list_] := Module[{},
   newList = {list[[1]]};
   xList = {list[[1, 1]]};
   yList = {list[[1, 2]]};
   For[i = 1., i <= Length[list], i++,
    For[j = i, j <= Length[list], j++,
      If[(list[[i, 1]] == list[[j, 1]] || 
           list[[i, 2]] == list[[j, 2]]) && (MemberQ[xList, 
            list[[j, 1]]] || MemberQ[yList, list[[j, 2]]]),
        newList = Append[newList, list[[i]]];
        newList = Append[newList, list[[j]]];
        xList = Append[xList, list[[i, 1]]];
        yList = Append[yList, list[[i, 2]]];
        xList = Append[xList, list[[j, 1]]];
        yList = Append[yList, list[[j, 2]]];
        ];
      ];
    ];
   DeleteDuplicates[newList]
   ];

getClusters[list_] := getClusters[list] = Module[{list1, list2},
    finalClusters = {};
    list1 = list;
    While[Length[list1] >= 1,
     list2 = findLinks[list1];
     finalClusters = Append[finalClusters, list2];
     (*Deletes from list1 those elements of list2... *)
     list1 = Complement[list1, list2];
     ];
    finalClusters
    ];

getClusters[data]
```

I am trying to implement another solution using `Select` or linked lists, but so far I am not getting anywhere.  Any ideas about how to speed up this task?

Comment: Related: [(4843)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4843/121) -- I think there is an even closer question but I cannot think of it at the moment.

Comment: Sektor, thanks for editing my post and making it look so much nicer.

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun:

```
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 1}, {1, 5}, {6, 2}, {7, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 4}, {0, 
    0}, {2, 3}, {6, 7}};
g = Cases[
   Subsets[data, {2}] /. {{{x_, a_}, {x_, b_}} :> 
      UndirectedEdge[{x, a}, {x, b}], {{a_, y_}, {b_, y_}} :> 
      UndirectedEdge[{a, y}, {b, y}]}, UndirectedEdge[_, _]];
gr = Graph[data, g, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
ConnectedComponents[gr]
```

[image]

```
{{{6, 7}, {6, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 5}},
{{4, 4}, {5, 4}},
{{7, 3}, {2,3}},
{{0, 0}},
{{3, 1}}}
```

Comment: "Just for fun?" I think `Graph` functionality *is* the way to go.  I seem to have a more efficient implementation leveraging `GatherBy` which I now included in my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this problem seemed like a 'barrel of monkeys' in my mind...a fun image from my childhood,,,I guess I was just using an alternative to other approaches...have not considered efficiency etc

Comment: @Mr.Wizard just looked at your implementation,,,as usual I learn a lot but I had already upvoted your answer :)

Comment: Thank you.  You also have my vote of course.

Comment: ubpdqn - what a nice way to show students about the collection of these points for small sets.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @MiguelBayona thank you...glad you found it useful:)

Answer (score 3):

#### Update

On reflection I think using [`ConnectedComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConnectedComponents.html) as referenced in the accepted answer to [(4843)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4843/121) and used by ubpdqn in his answer is probably the best approach.  Here is my implementation of that idea.

```
fn2[data_] :=
  UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ GatherBy[data, #] & /@ {First, Last} // 
    Flatten // Graph // ConnectedComponents
```

Tested on Question example:

```
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 1}, {1, 5}, {6, 2}, {7, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 4}, {0, 0}, {2, 3}, {6, 7}};

fn2[data] // Column
```

> ```
> {{6, 7}, {6, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 5}}
> {{4, 4}, {5, 4}}
> {{7, 3}, {2, 3}}
> {{0, 0}}
> {{3, 1}}
> ```

Speed on a large set:

```
SeedRandom[1]
big = RandomInteger[25000, {50000, 2}];

fn2[big] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.407, 1356}
> ```

---

### Old idea

This is probably pretty rough but I am in a rush.  Hopefully it <s>is correct and</s> serves as a basis for something that can be cleaned up.

```
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 1}, {1, 5}, {6, 2}, {7, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 4}, {0, 0}, {2, 3}, {6, 7}};

asc1 = GroupBy[data, First];
asc2 = GroupBy[data, Last -> First];

Union @@@ Map[asc2] /@ asc1[[All, All, 2]];
Union @@@ Map[asc1] /@ Union @ Values @ %
```

> ```
> {
>  {{0, 0}},
>  {{3, 1}},
>  {{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {6, 2}, {6, 7}},
>  {{2, 3}, {7, 3}},
>  {{4, 4}, {5, 4}}
> }
> ```

Comment: Mr. Wizard, Your solution is very good, and run so fast! However, as you mentioned, there is a bit of cleaning up that needs to be done to the final list.  I am in the process of doing that.  Thank you for sharing these ideas...I will post the additions I make.

Comment: @Miguel This needs further work.  I shall try to find the time for it today.

Comment: This is such a humbling experience for me.  Your updated version of the solution is so good and powerful.  I need to learn about ConnectedComponents and spend some time understanding your beautiful solution.  Thank you very much. Most definitely all you guys have my up vote!

Comment: @Miguel You're welcome; I am glad I could help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going with this, which tranposes the data, finds the unique values for X/Y using union and then selects X, and then Y, points which match each value:

```
With[{tr = Union /@ (data\[Transpose])}, {Cases[data, {#, _}] & /@ 
   First@tr, Cases[data, {_, #}] & /@ Last@tr}]
```

> {{{{0, 0}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 5}}, {{2, 3}}, {{3, 1}}, {{4, 4}}, {{5, 
>       4}}, {{6, 2}, {6, 7}}, {{7, 3}}}, {{{0, 0}}, {{3, 1}}, {{1, 
>       2}, {6, 2}}, {{7, 3}, {2, 3}}, {{4, 4}, {5, 4}}, {{1, 5}}, {{6, 
>       7}}}}

Comment: thanks for this reply: there is a lot in here for me to understand.  Will look at the code carefully and comment...