# Tree graph showing all simple paths with dead ends between two vertices in undirected graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have undirected weighted labeled graph. How i can generate and visualize tree graph, showing me all simple paths (and dead ends) from vertice A to vertice B? 
For example, for this graph

[image: this graph]

to show all simple paths with dead ends between vertices `1` and `2` i need to generate such tree

[image: such tree]

Comment: What have you tried? Look at `TreeGraph`, you can find all the paths using `FindPath` and you can visualise paths on a graph using `PathGraph` and `GraphHighlight`.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli What about deadlocks? I've added an example.

Comment: Could you please clarify what a deadlock is? (I am new to graphs, and am not sure I understand the precise definition, especially in the context of an undirected graph.) Do you mean deadlocks in the sense of [Wait_for graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait-for_graph)?  Or are you looking for "deadends" in the colloquial session (ending at an isolated vertex)?

Comment: @Rashid I meant dead ends in each session of finding simple path.

Comment: @Alex78191 Would you call `{1,4,6}` a "deadlock path" in [this graph](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki9Lq.png) ?

Comment: @AntonAntonov Yes.

Comment: @Alex78191, I believe my answer should find all the simple paths including dead ends (see [this tree](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl8c0.png) including {1,4,6} for the graph in Anton's comment). Could you please take a look a let me know if that is what you were looking for?

Comment: @Rashid yes, this that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@AntonAntonov's answer with the TriesWithFrequencies.m package is more elegant and useful, but here is a brute force approach without any extra packages.

(Note: This approach finds all simple paths including dead ends, *see comments for more details*. **Edited** to process more general graphs with more than 10 vertices.)

The main challenge is that the final tree should have the same graph vertices and edges depicted in different positions based on path order. One way to get around this problem is to relabel the vertices as we construct paths, and then use the `VertexLabels` function to relabel the vertices at the end.

**Step 1 - Define the undirected graph**

*Edit:* introduced `maxVertexValue` here to make subsequent code applicable to larger graphs

```
exampleGraph =  Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 4 <-> 5}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
maxVertexValue = Max[VertexList[exampleGraph]];
```

[image]

**Step 2 - Use`FindPath` to construct a list of all relevant paths.** This include the paths that successfully get from "1" to "2" as well as the lists that start from "1" but do not contain "2".

```
successfulPaths = FindPath[exampleGraph, 1, 2, 5, All];
unsuccessfulPaths =  Flatten[Table[Select[FindPath[exampleGraph, 1, x, maxVertexValue, All],!MemberQ[#, 2] &], {x, 3, maxVertexValue}], 1]
allPaths = Join[successfulPaths, unsuccessfulPaths];
```

Or more concisely:

```
allPaths = Flatten[Table[Select[FindPath[exampleGraph, 1, x, maxVertexValue, All], Last[#] == 2 || ! MemberQ[#, 2] &], {x, 2, maxVertexValue}],1];
```

Either case returns the following allPaths list:

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 5, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 3, 2}, {1, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 5, 3, 2}, {1, 5, 3}, {1, 4, 3}, {1, 5, 4, 3}, {1, 4, 5, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5, 4}, {1, 5, 3, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 4, 5}, {1, 4, 3, 5}}
```

**Step 3 - Give every vertix a path dependent name (EDITED to label each vertex with a path list)**. For example, the path list {1,5,3,2} can be relabeled as {{1},{1,5},{1,5,3},{1,5,3,2}}. These labels will help us group all 1->5 paths in the first step together.

```
relabeldPaths = Table[x[[1 ;; y]]], {x, allPaths}, {y, Length[x]}];
```

**Step 4 - Convert the relabeled paths list to a unique set of directed edges and vertices**. There is probably a much better way to do this, but I combined `EdgeList` with `PathGraph` as follows:

```
pathEdges = Flatten[Map[EdgeList[PathGraph[#, DirectedEdges -> True]] &, relabeldPaths] /. DirectedEdge -> Rule];
treeEdges = DeleteDuplicates[pathEdges];
treeVertices = VertexList[Graph[treeEdges]];
```

**Step 5 - Plot final graph using `VertexLabels` to select the `Last` part of each vertex name.** (EDITED to make labels clearer)

```
Graph[treeEdges, VertexSize -> Large, VertexLabels -> Table[x -> Placed[Last[x], Center], {x, treeVertices}], ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Here is a generalized module for this approach for quick copy/paste

```
pathTreeGraph[graph_, startingVertex_, endingVertex_] := 
 Module[{maxVertexValue, allPaths, relabeldPaths, pathEdges, 
   treeEdges, treeVertices}, maxVertexValue = Max[VertexList[graph]];
  allPaths = Flatten[Table[
     Select[FindPath[graph, startingVertex, x, maxVertexValue, All],           
     Last[#] == endingVertex || !MemberQ[#, endingVertex] &], 
     {x, DeleteCases[VertexList[graph], startingVertex]}], 1];
  relabeldPaths = Table[Flatten[x[[1 ;; y]]], {x, allPaths}, {y, Length[x]}];
  pathEdges = Flatten[Map[EdgeList[PathGraph[#, DirectedEdges -> True]] &, relabeldPaths] /. DirectedEdge -> Rule];
  treeEdges = DeleteDuplicates[pathEdges];
  treeVertices = VertexList[Graph[treeEdges]];
  Graph[treeEdges, VertexSize -> Large, 
   VertexLabels -> Table[x -> Placed[Last[x], Center], {x, treeVertices}], 
   ImageSize -> Medium]]

exampleGraph = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 4 <-> 5}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
pathTreeGraph[exampleGraph, 1, 2]
```

**UPDATE: Example with more than 10 vertices**

```
ButterflyGraph[2, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Medium]
pathTreeGraph[ButterflyGraph[2], 1, 2]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This answer does not find the deadlock paths. For example, for this graph `Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 4 <-> 5, 
  4 <-> 6}]` it will show the path `{1,4,6}` which is not a deadlock path.

Comment: On a separate note, I do like the tree of paths visualization approach.

Comment: @AntonAntonov, thanks for the help. I guess I don't understand what a deadlock is, because I would have thought that {1,4,6} was a deadlock since it ends in an isolated vertex (6). Here is the [graph](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki9Lq.png) and the [resulting tree](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl8c0.png) that my code produces. Do you know of any sites that might provide a nice definition of a deadlock path? (I tried searching online, but couldn't find anything that was very helpful with regard to deadlock paths and graphs.) Sorry, I am new to graphs, but am trying to use Mathematica to help me learn.

Comment: You are raising a valid concern -- I think we need to ask OP do provide a definition of deadlock paths. I am referring to this one: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait-for_graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait-for_graph) .

Comment: Thanks @AntonAntonov, I appreciate the help! I will also ask the OP above.

Comment: The OP does consider `{1,4,6}` of [the graph I mentioned](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki9Lq.png) to be a "deadlock path". (And in my answer I do not.) So your answer works for OP's question.

Comment: Thanks @AntonAntonov. In any case, I still prefer your answer and will definitely use your TriesWithFrequency.m package in the future for other projects. Thanks for helping me learn about this stuff.

Comment: Dead end (deadlock as was writed before) is vertice that have no neighbor vertices that have not been visited yet in path. All neighbours of the vertice were already visited in path.

Comment: @Rashid You can alter the algorithm for graphs with number of nodes greater or equal to 10.

Comment: @Alex78191, I have updated my answer to use path-dependent lists for each vertex (rather than strings). This also it to handle graphs with more than 10 vertices. I also cleaned up the label displays.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

> How i can generate and visualize tree graph, showing me all simple
>   paths (and deadlocks) from vertice A to vertice B?

This answer has a brute force solution and I have not tested it extensively. At least the visualization of the result tree graph should be useful.

### Creating the graph

```
graphRules = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 
   4 <-> 5};
gr = Graph[graphRules, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

### Paths

First we find all the paths from `v1`to `v2`:

```
{v1, v2} = {1, 2};

paths = FindPath[gr, v1, v2, Length[VertexList[gr]], All]

(* {{1, 2}, {1, 5, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 3, 2}, {1, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 5, 3, 2}} *)
```

### Deadlock paths

The deadlock paths -- as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait-for_graph) as locking of resources -- are found with brute force.

**1.** Find all inner veritces in the `v1`-to-`v2` paths:

```
innerVertices = Complement[Flatten[paths], {v1, v2}]

(* {3, 4, 5} *)
```

**2.** Find all paths from the inner vertices to `v2`:

```
innerVerticesPaths = 
 Map[# -> FindPath[gr, #, v2, Length[VertexList[gr]], All] &, innerVertices];
```

**3.** For each path $p$ of the `v1`-to-`v2` paths we select inner vertices paths $iv(p)$ that would produce deadlock paths if concatenated with $p$. This is done with the help of the following functions:

```
Clear[PickDeadlockPaths]
PickDeadlockPaths[headPath_, tailPaths_] :=  
  Block[{v = headPath[[-1]], ivs},
    ivs = headPath[[1 ;; -2]];
    If[Length[ivs] == 0, {},
     Union@
      Cases[tailPaths, {v, x___, d : (Alternatives @@ ivs), y___} :> {v, x, d}]
     ]
    ] /; Apply[And, Map[headPath[[-1]] == First[#] &, tailPaths]];
PickDeadlockPaths[___] := {};

Clear[MakeDeadlockPaths]
MakeDeadlockPaths[headPath_] :=
  Block[{dps},
   dps = PickDeadlockPaths[headPath, headPath[[-1]] /. innerVerticesPaths];
   If[Length[dps] == 0, {},
    Map[Join[headPath, Rest[#]] &, dps]
   ]
  ];
```

**4.** Here is the deadlock paths finding:

```
allDeadlockPaths = 
  Flatten[Map[
    Join @@ Table[MakeDeadlockPaths@Take[#, {1, i}], {i, 2, Length[#] - 1}] &,
     Select[paths, Length[#] > 2 &]], 1];

allDeadlockPaths = Union[Most /@ allDeadlockPaths]

(* {{1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 4, 3}, {1, 4, 5}, {1, 5, 3}, {1, 5, 4}, {1, 4, 3, 5}, {1, 4, 5, 3}, {1, 5, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 4, 3}} *)
```

### Tree with all paths

Using the package [TriesWithFrequencies.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/TriesWithFrequencies.m) we plot the requested tree:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/TriesWithFrequencies.m"]

ptrie = TrieCreate[Join[paths, allDeadlockPaths]][[2]];
TrieForm[ptrie]
```

[image]

The first element in each tree node corresponds to a graph vertiex, the second element is a traversal frequency.

(The package [TriesWithFrequencies.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/TriesWithFrequencies.m) is described in this blog post ["Tries with frequencies for data mining"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/tries-with-frequencies-for-data-mining/).)

Comment: Thanks Anton, +1. The `TriesWithFrequencies.m` package looks great. I will definitely use this in the future. I have actually be trying to define frequency trie structures for use with the Front-End argument string completion feature [113116](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113116/creating-compiled-search-trie-file-for-argument-string-completion).

Comment: @Rashid Thanks. You might also want to look into this document: ["Tries.pdf"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/Documentation/Tries.pdf), which has more extensive examples for that package.

Comment: I am having a problem opening the Github Tries.pdf link. My browser keeps crashing while the Github page tries to render the PDF (presumably using PDF.js). Have you ever run into this problem? Do you know of any work arounds? (If not, I could just download the file, but figured I would ask as others may run into the same problem.)

Comment: Sorry, no -- it works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I knew I was on to something but I didn't quite pull it together the first time.  Here is a second attempt, still probably not as clean as it should be, and not entirely general, but I think at least delivering on the promise of a recursive solution.

```
rls = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 5};
asc = GroupBy[Join @@ Permutations /@ rls, First -> Last];

f[r_, t_] := f[1][r, t]

f[i_][n___, r_, t_] := 
  Complement[r /. asc, {n, r}] //
   {n, r}[[i]] @@ 
     If[# === {}, r, f[i + 1][n, r, #, t] & /@ #] &

f[i_][n___, t_, t_] := t

f[1, 2] // TreeForm
```

[image]

Useful related questions:

- [Transform an expression into a graph that can be plotted with TreeGraph (not TreeForm)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11458/121)
- [Converting expressions to "edges" for use in TreePlot, Graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51629/121)
- [How to find all vertices reachable from a start vertex following directed edges?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4843/121)

#### Old answer

An idea:

```
rls = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 5};
asc = GroupBy[Join @@ Permutations /@ rls, First -> Last];

ClearAll[f]

f[n___, r_, t_] :=
  Complement[r /. asc, {n, r}] //
    If[# === {}, 〈n, r〉, f[n, r, #, t] & /@ #] &

f[n___, t_, t_] := 〈n, t〉

out = f[1, 2]
```

> ```
> {〈1, 2〉, {{〈1, 4, 3, 2〉, 〈1, 4, 3, 5〉},
>  {{〈1, 4, 5, 3, 2〉}}}, {{〈1, 5, 3, 2〉, 〈1, 5, 3, 4〉},
>  {{〈1, 5, 4, 3, 2〉}}}}
> ```

I am trying to think of a nice way to visualize this.  For the time being I'll borrow ideas from Rashid's answer:

```
out = Flatten[out] /. AngleBracket -> List;

BooleanGraph[Or,
  Sequence @@ (PathGraph @ Rest @ FoldList[Append, {}, #] & /@ out),
  VertexShapeFunction -> ({Disk[#, 0.2], White, Text[Last @ #2 ~Style~ 20, #]} &)
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relatively simple recursive solution, with explanation:

```
g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5}]
```

Start and end points:

```
s = 1;
t = 2;
```

Recursive descent:

```
f[soFar_] :=
 With[
    {current = soFar[[-1, 1]]},
    {unvisited = Complement[AdjacencyList[g, current], soFar[[All, 1]]]},
    If[current === t || unvisited === {},
     soFar,
     f@Append[soFar, {#, k++}] & /@ list @@ unvisited
   ]
 ]
```

Explanation:

- `soFar` is the vertices in the path so far
- `current` is the current node we are visiting. We will try to move on to all neighbours of `current` if they were not yet visited (see [`AdjacencyList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyList.html))
- If we reach the target `t`, we stop with the recursion. If there are no unvisited neighbours, we stop with the recursion.
- `k` is an extra label used to distinguish between events of encountering the same node through different paths.
- `list` is just a distinct head which we will flatten out later, without touching other parts of the expression.

[`PathGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PathGraph.html) chokes on vertex names that are lists, so we make our own ...

```
pathGraph[vertices_] := 
 Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[vertices, 2, 1]]
```

Compute all paths and merge them into a tree.

```
k = 0; 
GraphUnion @@ pathGraph /@ Flatten[f[{{s, k++}}], Infinity, list]
```

Labels vertices with their original name (i.e. do not display the value of `k`).

```
Graph[%, VertexLabels -> {{a_, b_} :> a}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To better understand how `f` works, try this:

```
k = 0;
f[{{s, k++}}]

% /. e : Except[_list] :> ToString[e] // TreeForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This expression tree reflects the structure of the tree we are building. The displayed leaf names are the paths used to get to that leaf.